# setDelegate explanation

Tags: ios, delegates

Hi i am new to iphone developement, can any one explain me why setDelegate is used, where we should use it.

```
[request setDelegate:sender];
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delegates are simply a design pattern; there is no special syntax or language support.

A delegate is just an object that another object sends messages to when certain things happen, so that the delegate can handle application-specific details the original object wasn't designed for. It's a way of customizing behavior without subclassing.

Answer (score 2):

Some classes, for example NSSpeechSynthesizer, include delegate support.  Unlike a protocol, failure to provide a delegate method does not provoke an error: the class always provides a method, but calls yours instead, if it exists.

For example,  NSSpeechSynthesizer has a method

```
-(void) speechSynthesizer:(NSSpeechSynthesizer*)sender 
        didFinishSpeaking:(BOOL)complete;
```

If you provide an identically declared method, in class Fred, it will be called instead of the synthesiser's own method, provided you have earlier done, in that class,

```
speech = [[NSSpeechSynthesizer alloc] initWithVoice:@"com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Albert"];

[speech setDelegate:self];
```

This will work, though the compiler will warn if you did not announce yourself as a delegate by

```
@interface Fred : NSObject <NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate>, in that 
{
```

. . .

(This example is adapted from Cocoa Programming... by Hillegass).